# Regex repeated group

Tags: php, regex

Having trouble with a repeated capturing group:

```
(?:\[)(?:(?:\s*?)([2-9AQTKJ][shcd])+?(?:\s*?)).*?(?:\])
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT8aC8/1)

Basically I want to match the card value (`As`, `8h` etc..) combinations inside the square brackets only

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What square brackets? I can't see any square brackets in your question. Put the text and your `regexp` into the question. Link to an external site for code testing only as a courtesy to the fellow developers that want to help you. The question becomes useless if the remote reference vanishes or is not available for some reason.

Comment: A repeated group will only capture the last occurrence. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex with a `\G` operator to match multiple substrings inside `[...]`:

```
(?:\[|(?!^)\G)\s*\K[2-9AQTKJ][shcd](?=[^\]]*])
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT8aC8/3)

In short, this PCRE regex will match a text that:

- `(?:\[|(?!^)\G)\s*\K` - starts with `[` or is at the end of the previous successful match followed with zero or more whitespace symbols
- `[2-9AQTKJ][shcd]` - matches 2 characters each of the defined sets
- `(?=[^\]]*])` - a positive lookahead checking if there is a closing `]` ahead of the current position

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/IwAh5i):

```
$re = '~(?:\[|(?!^)\G)\s*\K[2-9AQTKJ][shcd](?=[^\]]*])~'; 
$str = "[As 4h 8s] [ As 4h ] [As4h] As [ 4h "; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Note that a PCRE regex does not support a capture stack for each capturing group. If you set a `+` or `*` quantifier to a capturing group, only the last capture will be kept in the capture group memory buffer. It is possible in .NET, Python PyPi regex module and Boost, but not in PHP/PCRE. In PCRE, Oniguruma and other flavors supporting `\G` operator we can leverage it for this task.

Comment: Yeah i need this in PHP ... its complaining about an unknown modifier

Answer (score 2):

Is this want you want?

`/\[([^\]]+)\]/`

https://regex101.com/r/vT8aC8/2

EDIT ([Full PHP Solution](https://ideone.com/favskL))

```
$str= "[As 4h 8s] [ As 4h ] [As4h] As [ 4h ";

preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]+)\]/", $str, $matches);
$values = $matches[1];
$result = [];
foreach($values as $value)
{
   $parts = preg_split("/ /", $value, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
   foreach($parts as $part)
   {
    array_push($result, $part);
   }
}
var_dump($result); // $result will contain all the values you want
```

Comment: @ElGabbu: This is just the first step for a 2-step approach that consists in extracting the full substring with repeated values and then split with the string split methods available. The answer is certainly incomplete.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew Now I get what ElGabbu meant. I'll update my answer